# How to track messages which was omitted between camel pipelines?

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

I have 2 routes:

**first:**

```
....
.to("file://" + REST_FILES + "?fileName=${header.filename}");
```

**second:**

```
from("file://" + REST_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
....
```

But camel doesn't route files in case if I try to transfer same file repeatedly.

I want to have a place(callback for example) if file is not passed to the next pipeline. How can I achieve it?

P.S.

I tried to write:

```
 .to("file://" + REST_FILES + "?fileName=${header.filename}")
       .otherwise().process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                logger.info("{}",exchange);
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't invoke

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't route files?If noop=false it should consume the same file over and over again.

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti, I don't want to consume duplicates but I want to know if was attempt to put duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as you say `idempontent=true` which means it will not pickup files with the same name again (eg is a duplicate).

You can just test it by seeing if the file stays in that directory for a while, eg the file consumer does NOT pickup the file. If the file stays there, then its a duplicate.

Comment: just *file.isExists* ?

Comment: camel put  file into .camel directory, then put it near the .camel.

Comment: Moreover If I put file into *.camel* directory before app start - app will accept file with same name. but If this folder will be empty - applicatio will accept only one file

Comment: In some cases camel doesn't create a folder .camel. Non-determenistic strange behaviour from my point of view.

Comment: .camel is the folder where the file is moved after processing it, its not the idempotent repository database or something like that. The .camel folder is only created if needed, eg a file was processed and moved there. You can use delete=true if you want to delete the file instead. Read and study the Camel file component documentation !!!

Comment: I read http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html and tried to add **&move=null** in first url but it doesn't help. Can I avoid *.camel* directory?

Comment: I don't understand why camel move file into .camel

Comment: Set noop=true if you want to leave the file as-is